# R, add column to dataframe, count of substrings

Tags: r, count, character, substring, calculated-columns

This is my desired output:

```
> head(df)
    String numSubStrings
1       1       1
2       1       1
3 1;1;1;1       4
4 1;1;1;1       4
5   1;1;1       3
6       1       1
```

Hi, I have a data frame which has a "String" column as above. I would like to add a column "numSubStrings" which contains the number of substrings separated by ";" in "String".

I have tried

```
lapply(df, transform, numSubStrings=length(strsplit(df$Strings,";")[[1]]))
```

which gives me 1s in the numSubStrings instead.

Please advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `count.fields`. Usage would be something like:

```
> count.fields(textConnection(mydf$String), sep = ";")
[1] 1 1 4 4 3 1
```

You may need to wrap the `mydf$String` in `as.character`, depending on how the data were read in or created.

Or, you can try `lengths`:

```
> lengths(strsplit(mydf$String, ";", TRUE))
[1] 1 1 4 4 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gsub` to remove all the characters except the `;` and count the `;` with `nchar`

```
df$numSubStrings <- nchar(gsub('[^;]+', '', df$String))+1
df$numSubStrings
#[1] 1 1 4 4 3 1
```

Or another option is `stri_count` from `library(stringi)` to count the `;` characters and add 1.

```
library(stringi)
stri_count_fixed(df$String, ';')+1
#[1] 1 1 4 4 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `str_count` from `stringr` package.

```
x <- "    String
1       1       
2       1       
3 1;1;1;1       
4 1;1;1;1       
5   1;1;1       
6       1       "
df <- read.table(text=x, header=T)
df$numSubStrings <- str_count(df$String, "[^;]+")
df
#    String numSubStrings
# 1       1             1
# 2       1             1
# 3 1;1;1;1             4
# 4 1;1;1;1             4
# 5   1;1;1             3
# 6       1             1
```